# Understanding a Bugfix for building Valgrind from source

Tags: valgrind

I am trying to build Valgrind from source and ran into the same problem [other's have before me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10518734/valgrind-doesnt-accept-newest-version-of-glibc). The proposed solutions where all quite hacky, though, which is not the way I like to do things.
I also found something in the [Ubuntu bugtracker for the Valgrind package](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/valgrind/+bug/934127):

```
Proposed fix:

valgrind (1:3.7.0-0ubuntu2) precise; urgency=low

  * Allow glibc 2.15 in the configure checks. (LP: #934127)
      - Add 0009-glibc-215.patch, cherry-picked from upstream.
      - Add 0010-automake-1.11.2.patch by Gregorio Guidi.
      - Use dh-autoreconf instead of autotools-dev.

      -- Felix Geyer <email address hidden> Fri, 17 Feb 2012 12:14:44 +0100
```

This was accepted as fix for the bug, so I figured it might be the real solution. 
Yet I can't apply it just like that.

- what means `cherry-picked from upstream`?
- Neither searching in google nor in the downloaded source package found these patch files.
- Also the last point `Use dh-autoreconf instead of autotools-dev` is not clear to me.

Can someone translate the solution into a more applicable form?

Comment: It's the bugtracker for the Ubuntu-package, not the original Valgrind. The latter is what is meant with "upstream".

Comment: I see, but still don't get "upstream". Can you show exactly where 0009-glibc-215.patch is as an example?

Comment: Erik, I have now connected all the dots. HTH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to see if you can install the corresponding version through your package manager. If you really need to build it yourself, you will find the mentioned patches e.g. in [the `[..].debian.tar.gz` archive](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/valgrind).

If you look into the [Ubuntu tracker](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/93158534/valgrind_3.7.0-0ubuntu2.debdiff), you will find:

```
diff -Nru valgrind-3.7.0/debian/patches/0009-glibc-215.patch valgrind-3.7.0/debian/patches/0009-glibc-215.patch
--- valgrind-3.7.0/debian/patches/0009-glibc-215.patch  1970-01-01 01:00:00.000000000 +0100
+++ valgrind-3.7.0/debian/patches/0009-glibc-215.patch  2012-02-17 12:14:29.000000000 +0100
@@ -0,0 +1,30 @@
+Description: add support for glibc 2.15
+Origin: upstream, http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=20111229082456.D5FE6108870%40jail0086.vps.exonetric.net&forum_name=valgrind-developers
+
+Modified: trunk/configure.in
...
```

[The SourceForge URL above](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=20111229082456.D5FE6108870@jail0086.vps.exonetric.net&forum_name=valgrind-developers) tells you that this patch was committed in r.12323 to the Valgrind repo.

(The last remark about the autotools is specific to the Debian package building process, and has most likely nothing to do with your problem.)

Comment: Yes, it works this way. Just as a site note: It's a good exercise for learning the build process, to do it yourself, even if you could download the compiled package.