# Valgrind 2.20 to be used but requires glibc 2.1 - 2.3 version

Tags: valgrind, glibc

I want to install valgrind 2.20. It requires glibc 2.1-2.3 version. I am having glibc2.11? What can i change in configure file to solve the problem? I tried this link [valgrind doesn't accept newest version of glibc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10518734/valgrind-doesnt-accept-newest-version-of-glibc)
And pasted this

```
{ $as_echo "$as_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: result: 2.11 family" >&5
$as_echo "2.11 family" >&6; }
$as_echo "#define GLIBC_2_11 1" >>confdefs.h
DEFAULT_SUPP="glibc-2.X.supp ${DEFAULT_SUPP}"
DEFAULT_SUPP="glibc-2.34567-NPTL-helgrind.supp ${DEFAULT_SUPP}"
DEFAULT_SUPP="glibc-2.X-drd.supp ${DEFAULT_SUPP}"
;;
```

but it is showing the same error
configure: error: Valgrind requires the glibc version 2.1, 2.2 or 2.3

Comment: Why are you trying to use such an ancient version of valgrind on a modern machine?

Comment: Its for a project. I am using a modified valgrind which is 2.20version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What can i change in configure file to solve the problem?

It's a bug in autoconf, which has long since been fixed.

Just edit configure script to remove the glibc version check.

Comment: Now i can configure.But while make, its showing lot of warning about prototype and then it exits with error.

Comment: @SagarShah "but while make ...". 1. It's a different problem, so you should probably ask a new question. 2. You have provided absolutely *no* clues as to what the actual failure is. How do you expect anyone to help you?