# valgrind installation make error __longjmp_chk already defined

Tags: valgrind, ubuntu-10.04, glibc

I am trying to install valgrind 2.2.0 on ubuntu 10.04 having glibc 2.11. I have used [valgrind doesn't accept newest version of glibc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10518734/valgrind-doesnt-accept-newest-version-of-glibc) link. While make i am getting some error. The last 10 lines appearing on screen are

```
vg_libpthread.c:314: note: expected ‘const Char *’ but argument is of type ‘char *’
vg_libpthread.c:3292: warning: pointer targets in passing argument 4 of ‘my_assert_fail’ differ in signedness
vg_libpthread.c:314: note: expected ‘const Char *’ but argument is of type ‘const char *’
/tmp/ccGHnzp9.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/ccGHnzp9.s:2463: Error: symbol `__longjmp_chk' is already defined
make[4]: *** [vg_libpthread.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: *** [install] Error 2
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [install] Error 2
```

/tmp/ccGHnzp9.s file doesnt exist. I am unable to find whats wrong. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to install valgrind 2.2.0 on ubuntu 10.04

Valgrind 2.2.0 is *ancient* (Released on 31 August 2004) and can't be built without much hacking on a recent Linux system.

I can't think of any good reason to attempt building that particular Valgrind version either. Just use a newer release ([current](http://valgrind.org/downloads/valgrind-3.8.1.tar.bz2) release builds just fine on ubuntu 10.04 without any hacks).